# Error while connecting with wrong user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a project where I use Spring Boot, Spring Security and Spring MVC.
I configure Spring Security to authenticate with our company ldap.

When I try to log-in with a correct user, it works. But when I log-in with a wrong password or a wrong user, it returns an error :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:985) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:440) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.lang.Throwable.writeObject(Throwable.java:985) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
>       at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:62) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       ... 46 common frames omitted
>   Wrapped by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
>       at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:67) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
>       ... 44 common frames omitted
>   Wrapped by: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:166) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:128) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:85) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]
>       at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:409) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:331) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:211) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:187) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:163) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:121) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M4.jar:1.3.0.M4]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]

I don't understand why I have this error.I excepted to be redirected to the failure page (/login?error).

Here is my configuration :

```
@Autowired
private PortalUserDetailsService portalUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private LogoutSuccessHandler LogoutSuccessHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // Manage access authority to pages
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/about").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated().and()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login?error" ).and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(LogoutSuccessHandler);
}


@Override
public void configure( WebSecurity web ) throws Exception
{
    // This is here to ensure that the static content (JavaScript, CSS, etc)
    // is accessible without authentication
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, ldapUrl);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(getUserDetailsContextMapper());
    return provider;
}

private UserDetailsContextMapper getUserDetailsContextMapper() {
    return new UserDetailsContextMapper() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations dirContextOperations, String s, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
            PortalUserDetails portalUserDetails = portalUserDetailsService.loadZenithAttributesByUsername(s);
            try {
                portalUserDetails = portalUserDetailsService.addLdapAttributesFromContext(dirContextOperations.getAttributes(), portalUserDetails);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return portalUserDetails;
        }

        @Override
        public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails userDetails, DirContextAdapter dirContextAdapter) {
        }

    };
}
```

Do you have any idea what I can do to fix this error ?

**Solution :**
This problem was in my redis configuration.
I change the config like this :

```
@Primary
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String,ExpiringSession> redisTemplate2(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession> template = new RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession>();

    template.setHashValueSerializer(new LdapFailAwareRedisObjectSerializer());

    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

With this custom serializer :

```
public class LdapFailAwareRedisObjectSerializer implements RedisSerializer<Object> {

private Converter<Object, byte[]> serializer = new SerializingConverter();
private Converter<byte[], Object> deserializer = new DeserializingConverter();

static final byte[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new byte[0];

public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) {
    if (isEmpty(bytes)) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return this.deserializer.convert(bytes);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SerializationException("Cannot deserialize", ex);
        }
    }
}

public byte[] serialize(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return EMPTY_ARRAY;
    }

    try {
        return serializer.convert(object);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return EMPTY_ARRAY;
        //TODO add logic here to only return EMPTY_ARRAY for known conditions
        // else throw the SerializationException
        // throw new SerializationException("Cannot serialize", ex);
    }
}

private boolean isEmpty(byte[] data) {
    return (data == null || data.length == 0);
}
}
```

Comment: While trying to serialize the failed login response its breaking. If u run the app with valid login & capture respective trace too then probably we could isolate y its able to serialize on success but not onfailure:-org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RC1.jar:1.6.0.RC1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751094/spring-boot-with-session-redis-serialization-error-with-bad-active-directory-lda) please have a look at the solution.

I needed to replace the Redis Template that spring-session was using so that I could look for the com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx object and prevent spring from attempting to serialize it.

Mike Kowalski

Comment: Thanks for your answers. That was my problem. I change the serializer and now it works.